# Whether or not to use Kafka Streams and/or KSQL to denormalize datastreams from database

Tags: nosql, apache-kafka-streams, denormalization, cdc, ksqldb

After doing lots of reading on the web I finally reach out to this forum. My challenge is to denormalize transactional data from a database sourced via CDC into Kafka before writing it out into a NoSQL database, in this case Cassandra. What is the best way to join the transactional data with lookups from master tables? The issue I have is there are maybe 5 to 10 lookup tables per transactional table.

Trying to do this in a proof of concept using KSQL learned me to A) load the lookup tables as KTables and B) repartition the transactional stream and finally C) perform the join and write into a new topic. 
Following this approach, if I have 5 or 10 lookup tables that will generate lots and lots of data being sent around the cluster. I know Streams DSL can use the concept of GlobalKTable but that only works when the lookup tables are relatively small and in addition I prefer a higher level language like KSQL. Is there a better approach?

Comment: You will also potentially run into issues if the table you look up against can change.  Then how do you ensure that the data you are joining to is the data that appeared in those tables at the time the CDC data was generated.

Comment: If the data is correctly timestamped, Kafka Streams (and hence also KSQL that uses Kafka Streams internally) will ensure the correct processing order.

Comment: The lookup tables would also be sourced via CDC so in general it won't be a problem but indeed there is no guarantee: when transactions are close in time one could pass the other in Kafka.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is for ksqlDB to support non-key joins. So you should up-vote this issue that tracks that feature: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/4424

Until then, your approach of repartitioning the transactional stream to match the key of the lookup tables it the only viable solution.